# Text built on Bootstrap is not responsive in the Outlook email

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am testing an email with the HTML built on Bootstrap. The email goes to both, my desktop Outlook and my iPhone email.
On iPhone email the page is responsive. But the Outlook email on the desktop is not responsive at all. Each column has its one row.

Example:

In Outlook 365 email, the body looks like this:

```
 EQUIPMENT ID:
 BLABLABLA
 EQUIPMENT DESCRIPTION:
 EQUIPMENT BLABLABLA
 BUILDING:
 MAIN
 VENDOR:
 ABC123
```

On iPhone the above is shown differently:

```
EQUIPMENT ID:     BLABLABLA
EQUIPMENT DESCRIPTION:   EQ BLABLABLA
BUILDING:    MAIN
VENDOR:      ABC123
```

Could anyone see why Outlook email does not recognize Bootstrap?